# CodeIgniter display a redirect message

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I am currently using **XAMPP to serve up a CodeIgniter version 3.1.7 dynamic Web Application**.

**My goal is** to be able to see if a certain user was created/registered without looking at the DB (making it visible even for a normal user).

---

In previous versions of the framework, such as 3.0.1, one could solve this issue, displaying redirect messages, by:

- Using 'set_flashdata' & 'Redirect()' in a users.php file in **Controller**, as the
  following:

  ```
    $this->session->set_flashdata('user_registered', 'User has been registered');
    redirect('home/index');
  ```
- Using the following in the **View**:

  ```
  <?php if($this->session->flashdata('user_registered')): ?>

  <?php echo ($this->session->flashdata('user_registered')); ?>

  <?php endif; ?>
  ```

But as mentioned above, I am currently using CodeIgniter version 3.1.7 and **when registering the user**, **during the redirect**, it seems that the **CodeIgniter is resetting the data**.

> Note: A flash data should keep the "data" for the next request, and
>   after that request is made, it should automatically remove that data.

In order to solve the issue with this current version and to display a redirect message, I have tried using the following code in the users.php (**Controllers**):

```
      $this->session->set_flashdata('user_registered', 'User has been registered');
      $data = array('main_view' => 'home_view');
      $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
```

But I am still not able to see the redirect message...

I've checked the error log and the console for errors and nothing was found.

---

#### How can i achieve my goal?

Comment: do you get any errors? (check error logs and the console)

Comment: No errors in the console and none in the error.log (I am using XAMP).

Comment: Have you loaded the session library??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In their documentation, it's said the following from [flashdata](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=flashdata#CI_Session::flashdata):

> This is a legacy method kept only for backwards compatibility with
>   older applications. You should directly access $_SESSION instead.

You can do the same thing using $_SESSION directly (my example):

```
//first request
$_SESSION['flash'] = 'This is a simple flash message.';
//next request
$flash = $_SESSION['flash'];
unset($_SESSION['flash']); //flash is one time only
```

Comment: for future readers: Flashdata will be back in CI 4.x and looks to work like this: https://bcit-ci.github.io/CodeIgniter4/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata